# Battery Drains Fast when I installed CUDA and Cudnn

Tags: battery, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda

After installing Cuda and Cudnn I found that my battery drains very fast.
Earlier the standby was around 4-5 hours. Now it does not even last for 1.5 hours.
What is the solution for this.

Comment: On modern laptops there are techologys (like optimus) that disable the dedicated GPU while the notebook is in idle, in order to save battery using the much less powerful (and less power hungry) iGPU. I suspect installing nVidia developer drivers and tools disabled that. Check what is showing in nvidia control panel, under 3D configuration->preffered graphics processor

Comment: All the processes are working on my intel processor. Nvidia has been disabled for now.
I have even uninstalled CUDA and cudnn, still the same problem persist

Comment: Bring up Task Manager and have a look at how much CPU the top-CPU programs are using.  If the system is completely idle with nothing at all running (and any antivirus has been temporarily shut off), no individual process should be using more than 10% of one core (unless the system is doing an update).

Comment: Nothing of that sort is happening. In ideal state CPU usage is around 3-4%.
I bought new laptop few weeks ago so there is no scope of battery life being degraded.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running CUDA applications on the GPU?  Applications such as BOINC push a GPU just as far as possible in terms of performance, and that eats batteries up quickly.

Comment: I wanted to use tensorflow-gpu.
But as l installed CUDA I started facing this problem. I haven't used any other program on my Nvidia Graphic card.
I have even uninstalled CUDA still I'm facing the same problem.